# Moving a sprite with long taps

Tags: ios, swift, nodes

I have a simple question.

I want to move a sprite left or right, weather the player touches the left or the right side of the screen. It should continuously move until the player stops pressing the screen.

Please tell me how you would do that.

Thank you!

Comment: _Any_ details at all would be helpful. What sort of engine or framework are you using for the game? Do you have a code sample?

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you use "UIGestureRecognizerDelegate":

```
class TouchViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate{...}
```

Overrides:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
    if let touch: UITouch = touches.first as? UITouch{
        let touchLocation = touch.locationInView(self.view) as CGPoint
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    super.touchesEnded(touches, withEvent: event)
}
```

If you can share your code it will be easier to understand the problem...